# Openshift OKD and Centos 8

Tags: centos

I am new to the forum.  I own a small IT business, and I have been reading about the shift in cloud services to private cloud hosing.  I am interested in doing this for the clients I work with.

I am looking at using Centos 8 as my OS of choice, Openshift OKD as my orchestration software, and Nextcloud as my cloud software for my tenants.

The issue I am seeing here is that Openshift doesn't openly support CentOS 8 only 7.5.  Does anyone know this to be true / un-true?

The reason I am asking is because CentOS 7.5 is only supported til 2023, and I would hate to put a year or more into building this cloud platform, and have to worry about doing a major OS upgrade only 3 years from now.

If I have to use aging versions of CentOS does anyone know the potential complications I have to go through to upgrade to the CentOS 8?

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift 3 (last released late 2018, 3.11) runs on CentOS7 / RedHat7.

RedHat is currently building OpenShift 4, on top of RedHat CoreOS. While RedHat 8 can be used for compute nodes, your control panel would have to use RH-CoreOS. It's been over a year now, and the first community releases are showing up, based on Fedora CoreOS.

So, short anwser: there won't be an OKD release for CentOS 8. Still, you can try out [OpenShift 4](https://www.openshift.com/blog/okd4-is-now-generally-available), if you're looking for the last release.

Depending on your requirements, right now, OKD3 could still be relevant, though it's getting quite old (packages were not re-built, after initial 3.11 release, the registry-console image has been broken in dockerhub for weeks, ...).

Nowadays, I'm tempted to recommend going with Kubernetes, when considering OpenShift 4. If you're into Ansible, check out [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)